# To create map of array of map in golang

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go

I want to create a json in golang for which I need to first create map of the following:

```
{"inputs": [{"data": {"image": {"url": "SOME_URL"}}}]}
```

how to create this map on golang. (for now even hardcoded will also work for me)

Comment: Take the Tour of Go once more. You'll find the explanations very clear.

Answer (score 2):

### In a struct:

```
type SomeData struct {
    Inputs []struct {
        Data struct {
            Image struct {
                URL string `json:"url"`
            } `json:"image"`
        } `json:"data"`
    } `json:"inputs"`
}
```

But if we wanted to be able to add things individually, AND be more idiomatic, we would do it like this:

```
type Image struct {
    URL string `json:"url"`
}

type Data struct {
    Image Image `json:"image"`
}


type Input struct {
    Data Data `json:"data"`
}

type SomeData struct {
    Inputs []Input `json:"inputs"`
}
```

Then, of course, we could always just use a map:
`someData := map[interface{}]interface{}{}`

It really just depends on which route you'd like to go. I suggest the second one as it gives you better fine-grained tooling without any pesky dirty tricks or code-clutter.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

neededMap := make(map[string][]map[string]map[string]map[string]string)